# RemoteApp : Save files on client's local profile

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, user-profile, remoteapp

I have a RemoteApp collection with all office programs (Word, Excel, ...) on my Windows Server 2016 with RDS installed.

When I launtch a program (like Word) on my client Windows 10 and then I want to save, it saves by default on my Administrator's session on the Windows Server 2016. That's not what I want.

How can I save only and by default on my user profile on the client?

Comment: Change the default save location in the options in each Office app.

Comment: I found the solution : I have installed an administrative template for Office (to modify Office with GPO) and I can change the default save location.